# How to get the value in an array inside an array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Can someone help me, I want to get the name of the owner and petname in the array and display it on the .blade.php.

My array is shown below.
[array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgQvH.png)

**controller code**
[controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVZad.png)

**.blade.php code**
[blade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCWkw.png)

Comment: Please next time, include the code as text and not as images. Firstly the images can disappear and the question will not provide value to other users. Secondly it makes it hard to copy paste etc for explanations.

Comment: Please review [ask] and [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Thank you for the reminders, and sorry it is my first time posting here. But, I will keep that in mind, and thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly using the new array syntax is considered best practice. I would recommend going forward looking into models, instead of using the `DB` facade.

If you have the following array, it will act as an key value array or in some languages called hashmaps. You can fetch the elements of the array and by the key. You can loop through the key with foreach, but it is intended to be used by key access.

```
public function view()

    ...

    $data = [
        'owner' => $owner,
        'petname' => $petname,
    ];

    return view('someview', compact('data'));
}
```

In your blade template, you can simply access the data, with the key access, the syntax is `$arr['key']`. These initial values are objects, so after the first access, access em with the object accessor which is ->.

```
<td> {{ $data['owner']->name }} </td>

<td> {{ $data['petname']->name }} </td>
```

Comment: Thank a lot, it works. I can now access the values inside the array. Stay safe for you and God bless <3